# How to insert data in specific category if it is not defined in Django model's field?

Tags: django

I have a Django project where I created two models: `Category` and `Shop`. Each shop might have only one category. If I didn't define a shop's category I want it to be in `Without category` section at template. How do I set a default value?

My models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class DemoShop(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='Cat')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

When I write:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Cat', default='Without category')
```

It has no effect in my database and It doesn't show in `Without category` section at my template. If I haven't put a shop in a certain category I want it to be shown in `Without category` at the page, like:

```
Products:
    -lorem;
    -testshop;
Watch:
    -keram;
    -pollop;
Without category:
    (All shop what I haven't define a category in DB)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ForeignKey` model field default value is the primary key of the model instance it references (unless you set `to_field` on your ForeignKey to point to some other field of the referenced model).
Please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default

If you want to set the default category for the `DemoShop` to be "Without value" you can create a classmethod that creates/returns if exists the `Category` of the name "Without category" (I arbitrarily chose the `position=5` argument value for the `get_or_create` method):

```py
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   position = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.name}'

   @classmethod
   def get_default_pk(cls):
       obj, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
           name="Without category",
           position=5
       )
       return obj.pk
```

Then you can use the defined classmethod to get your dummy category of the name "Without category" (assuming that `Category` and `DemoShop` models are defined in the same models.py file:

```py
class DemoShop(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='Cat', default=Category.get_default_pk())
```

---

If for some reason you really cannot/don't want to insert the dummy category of the name "Without category" into your database, you can set the category field on your `DemoShop` model to allow for blank input and to be nullable and then define a custom method as a getter for the related category name:

```py
class DemoShop(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='Cat', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

    def get_category_name(self):
        if self.category is None:
            return "Without category"
        return self.category.name
```

And then use this method in your template to get the category name for your DemoShop instances.